# In HTML+CSS is there a general way to suppress line breaks between certain characters?

Tags: html, css

Wikipedia's standard footnoting produces HTML of the form:

```
Here is an example sentence with a footnote.<sup>[1]</sup> And continue...
```

The result generally looks like:

> Here is an example sentence with a footnote.<sup>[1]</sup> And continue...

If the RH side of the display comes close after "footnote." then the result is either:

> Here is an example sentence with a footnote.<sup>[1]</sup>
> And continue...

or

> Here is an example sentence with a
> footnote.<sup>[1]</sup> And continue...

It always looks humanly clean: it holds together the full stop and superscripted footnote reference so that it never line-breaks.  Try it.  With any Wikipedia article, gradually resize the browser horizontally so that the text reflows. Observe how the relevant part (equivalent to "footnote.<sup>[1]</sup>") is never subject to line-breaking.

Yet my own very simple HTML/CSS is subject to line-breaking, so that if the screen width needs to break immediately after the word-plus-full-stop "footnote.", the output can then be the ugly:

> Here is an example sentence with a footnote.
> <sup>[1]</sup>  And continue...

Yet somehow Wikipedia's simple `...footnote.<sup>[1]</sup>` achieves its cleanness. Note that it is that simple; no `<nobr>` or similar. What are the relevant parts of HTML (probably more likely CSS), please?

I've had a look through the HTML and some of the CSS, but cannot see how they achieve this suppression of line-breaking at such points.

Nor can I see in the HTML and CSS documentation how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the specification, but through simple trial-and-error I found that the `uncode-bidi: isolate` declaration does what you want (at least on my machine):

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

sup {
  unicode-bidi: isolate;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Here is an example sentence with a footnote.<sup>[1]</sup> And continue...
</p>
```

Comment: That seems to produce the right effect. Thank you! 

I hadn't come across "unicode-bidi" before.  Even if I had, I wouldn't have thought to look there (bi-directionality) for addressing this problem (of holding text unbroken for this purpose); the connection is not intuitively obvious.

I have now Googled it and found some description of it.  I think I can see the general outline of what it is trying to do and why it might be working.

I've just applied it to my own HTML/CSS and it seems to be working nicely.

Thanks again.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @DavidLee Please (if you can explain it) either edit my answer or provide your own, for other people to understand why it works that way. I'm actually curious myself!

Comment: I don't know nearly enough about the deep inner workings of the rendering of HTML and CSS. But I think a clue might be here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-bidi/#bidi-isolation-solution and here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#unicode-bidi

Answer (score -1):

Just use the white-space css property and apply the nowrap value to the "sup" tag. So there will be no line break and it will stay stuck to the quote that precedes it.